# Ordenar registros que contenham números no final

Tags: mysql, sql, classificação, order

Tenho uma tabela com os seguintes registros:

```
+----+------------+--------------+
| id |   title    |     url      |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  1 | Olá Mundo! | ola-mundo-1  |
|  5 | Olá Mundo! | ola-mundo-3  |
|  6 | Olá Mundo! | ola-mundo-10 |
|  7 | Olá Mundo! | ola-mundo-2  |
|  8 | Olá Mundo! | ola-mundo-15 |
+----+------------+--------------+
```

Preciso ordenar pela coluna `url` considerando o número que existe no final.

```
+----+------------+--------------+
| id |   title    |     url      |
+----+------------+--------------+
|  1 | Olá Mundo! | ola-mundo-1  |
|  7 | Olá Mundo! | ola-mundo-2  |
|  5 | Olá Mundo! | ola-mundo-3  |
|  6 | Olá Mundo! | ola-mundo-10 |
|  8 | Olá Mundo! | ola-mundo-15 |
+----+------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provavelmente seria o caso de repensar na organização do DB, talvez separando esta informação em duas partes (armazenando só o número, se o resto repete) ou armazenando em colunas separadas.

Você não deu muitos critérios sobre o formato da coluna `url`.

Se o tamanho for fixo, basta isso para extrair só a parte numérica:

```
 SELECT id, title, url FROM tabela ORDER BY SUBSTRING(url, 11);
```

A função `SUBSTRING` extrai um "pedaço" de outra *string*. No exemplo acima, estamos extraindo à partir da posição 11, logo após `ola-mundo-`.

Agora, imagino que você queira ordenar numericamente, para que números como 10, que inicia em 1, não fique antes de 2, 3, 4 etc. Neste caso, basta forçar uma comparação numérica e não de string:

```
 SELECT id, title, url FROM tabela ORDER BY 0 + SUBSTRING(url, 11);
```

Como reforçado pelo colega [@jlHertel](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/14919) nos comentários, toda ordenação que é feita deste jeito não aproveita índices no MySQL, que não tem opção de indexar nem condicionalmente, nem usando expressões, e é por isto a sugestão de reorganização dos dados.

Comment: Importante lembrar que esta ordenação de strings com funções não utiliza indices. Portanto o melhor caso seria separar a informação conforme o Bacco sugeriu.

Comment: @jlHertel incorporei a observação no texto da pergunta.